# What is the best way to communicate between a node.js server and a C# client?

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a server running on node.js, using socket.io and HTML5 clients.
I also have a more specific client written in C#, because it's running on Microsoft's PixelSense.

My primary idea was to use C# socket.io implementations, but i didn't found one of these working implementation :(

But, the good point is that the node.js is running on the pixelsense device. I can use more rustic solutions like file's pipes.

In your opinion, what is the best way to communicate between my node server and my C# client running on the same machine (windows) ?

Do you know a working implementation of socket.io in C# ? A small hack using files ? A use of a intermediate server ?

Performances and reactivity are a plus.

Thanks

Comment: There are many C# socket implementations listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985629/html5-websockets-client-for-net

Comment: Yes but it's websocket implementations and not socket.io implementations. But it's could be a good start. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

What's the reason of socket.io usage? I think it's definitely better to use TCP Sockets for communication between this platforms. This way you can easy add SSL support and don't think about compatibility.

Comment: If traffic is not too heavy you can also use HTTP. HTTP might a bit of an overkill for communication on the same machine but it's easy to get going and there is a lot of support for it on both C# and Node.js

Comment: The major reason is that i like the events in sockets.io. The integration with node.js and web devices are also great.

So why not also use socket.io between this platforms ?

TCP sockets seems to be a too much complicated method compared to the allowed time for the project. HTTP was in my opinion the default solution, but i prefer keep a solution with events and an elegant code.